# Parsing site with csrf

Tags: java, spring-boot, parsing, jsoup

Could you please advise on how to deal with parsing the dns-shop website (https://www.dns-shop.ru/)? I need to retrieve some data from the page using Jsoup. It's said that dns-shop has good protection against CSRF.

```
private String url = "https://www.dns-shop.ru/";

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public Document connectAndGet() throws IOException {
        return Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .timeout(10000)
                .referrer("https://google.com")
                .get();
    }
```

When I try to run the code, I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error. I should also mention that I don't encounter such issues with resources like eBay and Amazon, where everything connects correctly. I suspect the problem might be related to cookies or even tokens. I need to access the page and extract data from it.

Error by this code is:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401, URL=[https://www.dns-shop.ru/]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:912) ~[jsoup-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:851) ~[jsoup-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:345) ~[jsoup-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:330) ~[jsoup-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at com.xxx.connectAndGet(ParseSite.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.